# Change css display of multiple elements using class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Fairly new to Javascript here. I have a to do list, and I am in the process of adding a feature to Hide all checked items (which have a class .checked).
The idea i have, is to add a display property to the class(that all checked items receive) but how do I do it? Is there any other way for me to be able to add a display property to all of the checked items?

Here's the code (didn't include the other css as it was unnecesary):

```js
//ADD NEW ELEMENT SECTION


function newElement() {
  var inputval = document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var lichild = document.createTextNode(inputval);

  li.appendChild(lichild);
  if (inputval === '') {
    alert('you must put something in the textbox!');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mylist').appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById('inputnewlist').value = "";


//REMOVE BUTTON SECTION
    
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var buttonval = document.createTextNode('x');
  button.classList.add("exit");

  button.appendChild(buttonval);
  li.appendChild(button);
  
  var exit = document.querySelectorAll('.exit');
  for (b = 0; b < exit.length; b++) {
  exit[b].addEventListener('click', removeButtonParent);
  }
  
}//end of create newelement function

var exit = document.querySelectorAll('.exit');
for (z = 0; z < exit.length; z++) {
exit.addEventListener('click', removeButtonParent);
}
    
function removeButtonParent() {
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
}

//ENTER KEY PRESS-BUTTON PRESS
function enterfunction(event) {
var key = document.getElementById('inputnewlist');
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('addbutton').click();
}}

//CHECK BUTTON SECTION
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    event.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);

//HIDE CHECKED LIST ITEMS
function hideCheck() {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
        var checkLI = document.querySelectorAll('.checked');
        checkLI.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        var checkliELSE = document.querySelectorAll('.checked');
        checkLI.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

```css
.checked {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  
  <div id="formcontainer">
   <h1 class="title"> To Do List </h1>
   <input type="text" name="inputnewlist" id="inputnewlist" placeholder="Add thing to do.." onkeydown="enterfunction(event)">
   <button onclick="newElement()" class="addbutton" id="addbutton">Add</button>
  </div>
  
  <ul id="mylist">
  </ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="hidecheck" onchange="hideCheck()"> <label for="hidecheck"> Hide the checked list items</label>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: just a little ps: i am aware of the error when checking the checkbox, but i do not know any of any other way to fix it, so i left it there so you guys can get an idea of what i wanted to achieve and do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code by adding the style 1 by 1.

```
function hideCheck() {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
        var checkLIs = document.querySelectorAll('.checked');
        for (let i = 0; i < checkLIs.length; i++){
           checkLIs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! forgot about for loops haha

Comment: Yes. As ```querySelectorAll``` return  an ```array-like```  thing that you can loop through it.